# Include reduce in view output?

Tags: couchdb

Since I started using pagination (using startkey), I can no longer get the total number of *filtered* records in the view as `total_records` just gives me the unfiltered total, and `rows.length` gives me just the current 'page' length.

So I've added a reduce function for `_count` to give me the number of relevant records, but now it seems I have to run two queries.

One with `reduce: true` to get the number of records, and then again with `reduce: false` to get the actual data.

Is there a way of running the query once (I've tried `include_reduce: true` which would seem logical, but no).

Comment: No, you need to do two queries.